# How to merge rows (items) of same relation in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm new to apache pig. 
I have data like below.

```
tempdata = 

(linsys4f-PORT42-0211201516244460,dnis=3007047505)
(linsys4f PORT42-0211201516244460,incoming_tfn=8778816235,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,state=NC)
(linsys4f-PORT42-0211201516244460,language=ENGLISH)
(linsys4f-PORT42-0211201516244460,outcome=Transfer to CSR,exitType=Transfer,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019)
(linsys4f-PORT43-0211201516245465,outcome=Transfer to CSR,exitType=Transfer,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019)
(linsys4f-PORT44-0211201516291287,dnis=3007047505)
(linsys4f-PORT44-0211201516291287,incoming_tfn=8778816235,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,state=NC)
```

I need to merge the rows according to the key that is insys4f-`PORT42-0211201516244460, linsys4f-PORT43-0211201516245465 & linsys4f-PORT44-0211201516291287.`
and the output should like:

```
(linsys4f-PORT42-0211201516244460,dnis=3007047505,incoming_tfn=8778816235,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,state=NC,language=ENGLISH,outcome=Transfer to CSR,exitType=Transfer,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019)

(linsys4f-PORT43-0211201516245465,dnis=3007047505,incoming_tfn=8778816235,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,state=NC,language=SPANISH)

(linsys4f-PORT43-0211201516245465,outcome=Transfer to CSR,exitType=Transfer,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019,dnis=3007047505,incoming_tfn=8778816235,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,state=NC).
```

How can i merge this. Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Group BY](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP) Operator and [Flatten](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator) to solve this:

I have separated your first field into link, portname, port id for clearrer picture

```
A = LOAD '/home/coe_user_1/del/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(port : CHARARRAY, dnis : CHARARRAY, incoming_tfn : CHARARRAY, tfn_location : CHARARRAY, ivr_location : CHARARRAY,state : CHARARRAY, language : CHARARRAY, outcome : CHARARRAY, exitType : CHARARRAY, exitState : CHARARRAY);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
        FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(port, '-', 3)) as (link: chararray, port: chararray, pid: int),
        dnis AS dnis,
        incoming_tfn AS incoming_tfn,
        tfn_location AS tfn_location,
        ivr_location AS ivr_location,
        state AS state,
        language AS language,
        outcome AS outcome,
        exitType AS exitType,
        exitState AS exitState;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE
        port AS port,
        --pid AS pid,
        dnis AS dnis,
        incoming_tfn AS incoming_tfn,
        tfn_location AS tfn_location,
        ivr_location AS ivr_location,
        state AS state,
        language AS language,
        outcome AS outcome,
        exitType AS exitType,
        exitState AS exitState;
D = GROUP C BY port;

E = FOREACH D GENERATE
        group AS port,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.dnis)) AS dnis, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.incoming_tfn)) AS incoming_tfn, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.tfn_location)) AS tfn_location, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.ivr_location)) AS ivr_location ,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.state)) AS state,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.language)) AS language, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.outcome)) AS outcome,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.exitType)) AS exitType,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(C.exitState)) AS exitState ;

DUMP E;
```

Output:

```
(PORT42,outcome=Transfer to CSR,language=ENGLISH,incoming_tfn=8778816235,dnis=3007047505,exitType=Transfer,,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019,,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,,,,state=NC,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
(PORT43,outcome=Transfer to CSR,exitType=Transfer,exitState=SETDIR2^7990019,,,,,,)
(PORT44,incoming_tfn=8778816235,dnis=3007047505,tfn_location=Ashburn Avaya,,ivr_location=Ashburn Avaya,,state=NC,,,,,,,,,,,)
```